# Change class_key permission in Modx Revo

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am looking for the permission to change the class_key of an resource but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

I need it so my client can change the resource-type of some resources by himself. He created some symlinks but they have to be weblinks.

Answer (score 0):

Modx have permission "class_map" but it prevents any changes of this field. If you want to exclude certain types of resources you can use this plugin at event "OnManagerPageAfterRender".

```
<?php
// comma separated list of excluded from class list
$excluded = 'modSymLink,modStaticResource';

switch ($modx->event->name) {
    case 'OnManagerPageAfterRender':
        $controller_path = $controller->config['controller'];
        if ($controller_path == 'resource/update' || $controller_path == 'resource/create') {
            $my_js = "<script>Ext.onReady(function() {
                Ext.getCmp('modx-resource-class-key').baseParams.skip = 'modXMLRPCResource,".$excluded."';
            });</script>";
             $controller->content = preg_replace('~(</head>)~i', $my_js . '\1', $controller->content);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: I already tried class_map and can confirm that it changes nothing ^^ But I apsolutely need to enable my client to change the class_key/resource-type ... And I don't get the purpose of this plugin :/ ... but thanks already! You help me out a lot in the last days :)

Comment: This plugin exclude from selection list of class_key "modSymLink" and  "modStaticResource" types, just try :)

Comment: hmm ok, I understand it now but sadly it is not a solution because there is no output to filter ;) But thanks!